# Jquery Datatables server side processing SUM of a column

Tags: java, spring-mvc, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables with server side processing to implement a reports page in my application. A report is generated on a button click. I am using a hibenate query to calculate the total of the report(which is sum of all elements in one of the columns) which is being called even on page switch. For performance improvement, I am trying to make it work in such a way that, the total is calculated only when the page number is one. I tried using static and it ended up showing totals of one user to the other (when logged in at the same time in different browsers). Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The start row is given on every page request.  Test it and if start = 0, do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bindrid. I definitely can do that even when page number =1. Bu the issue is, how am I going to store the result for future use(when navigated to next page)

Comment: Use localStorage or sessionStorage